# How to avoid this degree to radian error?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, core-plot, pie-chart

While developing pie chart using core plot I added animation for that for given code

```
    CABasicAnimation *rotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
   CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians(360), 0, 0, 1);
   rotation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];  
    rotation.duration = 10.0f;
    [pieChart addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"rotation"];
```

This code gives following error Semantic Issue:

```
Implicit declaration of function 'DegreesToRadians' is invalid in C99
```

What can I do for avoid this?

And also run time it gives following error:

```
Apple_o  Linker id error  "_DegreesToRadians", referenced from:
```

Thanks and Regards

Vijayakumar

iOS Developer at Rhytha

https://rhytha.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just define a macro like:

```
#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

And change your method like:

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_RADIANS(360), 0, 0, 1);
```

Comment: @VijayakumarNL: with pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
```

write this code at top of your .m file where you want to convert

let me know whether is it working or not

Answer (score 0):

For simple angles, just use radians:

```
Transform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(2 * M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
```

A quick list of typical angles:

```
Degrees | Code
--------+---------
360     | 2 * M_PI
180     | M_PI
90      | M_PI_2
45      | M_PI_4
```